# Javascript Number Method not returns expected value

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have tried JavaScript **Number** method and it returns unexpected results.

If i pass ***192000000000000005*** value into Number() method. It returns ***192000000000000000***, without **5**.

If I Pass **19200000000000005** value, it returns **19200000000000004**, which is unexpected.

What is that meaning of those results?  You can find the below screenshot too.

***Chrome Console***:

[image]

Comment: see `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` - that number is 21 times larger than the maximum "safe" integer representable by floating point

Comment: JavaScript numbers are ***always*** 64-bit floating bit numbers.

Comment: If I pass 19 digit number it returns as 18 digit number?

Comment: The numbers you're trying to make are too big to be represented exactly.

Comment: @Raja - 192,000,000,000,000,005 is **18** digits ... what 19 digit number are you "passing" ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I need to pass this 192000000000000005, and if i pass this to Number() I didn't lose the last integer 5.

Comment: `I didn't lose the last integer 5` - actually you **did** lose it ... yes, but it's **the same number of digits** ... you just get a number that is 5 less than the number you "passed in", i.e. the **5** becomes a **0** - due to the reasons explained above - count the digits ... you'll see you are wrong - and still, no 19 digit number

Comment: Let me save you the hassle of asking more about this ... `192000000000000005` can not be represented by a `Number` in javascript, due to the limitations of 64bit floating point representation ... the Maximum integer that is safe (i.e. all integers up to that integer can be represented without gaps) is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === 9,007,199,254,740,991 - you can see that's 16 digits - so 18 digits is not safe, and 19 (whatever, you've never tried) won't work either - note 9007199254740991 is `2**53 - 1` - 64bit floating point has a 53 bit mantissa

Comment: @JaromandaX well written comment. Please put it as an answer because it indeed answers the question `What is that meaning of those results?` :)

Comment: @JaromandaX is there any MSDN or Mozilla docs link that explains the same?

Comment: I wouldn't trust MSDN - probably is on Mozilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192000000000000005 can not be represented by a Number in javascript, due to the limitations of 64bit floating point representation

The Maximum integer that is safe (i.e. all integers up to that integer can be represented without gaps) is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === 9,007,199,254,740,991

you can see that's 16 digits - so 18 digits is not safe, and 19 (whatever, you've never tried) won't work either -

Note, the actual definition of MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is

> the largest integer `n`, where `n` and `n + 1` are both exactly representable as a `Number` value

```js
console.log(9007199254740991) //=> 9007199254740991  
console.log(9007199254740992) //=> 9007199254740992  
console.log(9007199254740993) //=> 9007199254740992
```

> So, while `9007199254740992` is representable as a Number, because `9007199254740993` also has the same value when stored in a 64bit float, it is not "safe"

note `9007199254740991` is `2**53 - 1` - which makes sense when you know that 64bit floating point has a 53 bit mantissa

[Mozilla Developer Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)